# WinForms equivalent of HTML <optgroup>

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface

Is there a desktop .NET-based equivalent of the [`<optgroup>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp) functionality for comboboxes on html pages?

Comment: What kind of an influence does <optgroup> has for combo-boxes on html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to group winform combobox items together as in the html `<optgroup>` tag.

You may have to do some kind of custom control.

Comment: Or buy one in, I guess. Oh well. :)